# Pandas isin() function symmetry?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When I do `match=a.isin(b)` the number of matches doesnt equal the number of matches in `match2=b.isin(a)`. Here a and b are dataframe columns (series) and a match is each "True" value in the column. I think of `a.isin(b)` as a function returning "True" for those elements in a found in b and `b.isin(a)` as a function returning "True" for those elements in b found in a. I would expect an equal amount of matches, why does it not? I have `len(match)>>len(match2)`, can this be possible?

Comment: Do you have duplicates? Only when both are non-duplicated would `a.isin(b)` and `b.isin(a)` have the same number of matches

Comment: If at least one of them contains duplicate matching elements, yes.  For instance, `a = pd.Series([1, 2, 3])` and `b = pd.Series([1, 1, 0])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confused on what `isin` does.

```
a = pd.Series([1,1,1,2,2,3])
b = pd.Series([1,2,2,4])
```

then `a.isin(b)` has the same length (and index) as `a`:

```
pd.Series([True, True, True, True, True, False])
```

while `b.isin(a)` has the same length (and index) as `b`:

```
pd.Series([True, True, True, False])
```

What will be the same? The **unique values**:

```
set(a[a.isin(b)]) == set(b[b.isin(a)])
```